# Python multiprocessing: where should join() be called, if process' children have grandchildren?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Here is a toy problem I am working with:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def task2():
    print "I am doing something important."

def task1():
    listOfProcesses = []
    for i in range(5):
        process = mp.Process(target=task2)
        process.start()
        listOfProcesses.append(process)

def task0():
    listOfProcesses = []
    for i in range(5):
        process = mp.Process(target=task1)
        process.start()
        listOfProcesses.append(process)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    task0()
```

Now, I am having trouble understanding where join should be called in such a scenario.

If I change `task0`'s definition like so:

```
def task0():
    listOfProcesses = []

    for i in range(5):
        process = mp.Process(target=task2)
        process.start()
        listOfProcesses.append(process)

    for process in listOfProcesses:
        process.join()
```

Everything then seems to work correctly, but I don't understand what I am really doing here. `task1` only starts its children, it does not join them. So what does joining `task0` mean for `task1`?

Comment: @roippi I made a typo, and I have fixed it up plus added a little to make where I call `task0` clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`join` is fairly simple in concept - `x.join` says "the current thread (i.e. process) of execution cannot proceed past *this* point until `x` terminates."

So, in general you don't want your **main** thread to proceed past some point until all your workers are done doing their work.  Since you execute `task0` in your main thread, doing a `join` there prevents your main thread from proceeding past that point until all your workers (both `task1` *and* `task2`) are done.

## But wait, I didn't `join` in `task1`!

That's right.  But `task1`'s process still won't terminate until all its `task2`s are finished.  This has to do with the POSIX concept of [*process groups*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) - a parent process will not terminate until all its child processes are terminated.  So, let's look at the output of this reduced example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep

def task2():
    sleep(1)
    print "I am doing something important."

def task1():
    for i in range(2):
        process = mp.Process(target=task2)
        process.start()

    print 'task1 done'

def task0():
    process = mp.Process(target=task1)
    process.start()
    process.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    task0()
    print 'all done'
```

output:

```
task1 done
I am doing something important.
I am doing something important.
all done
```

So as you can see, `task1` reached its end but did not terminate until its child processes did - which meant that our `join` block in `task0` correctly blocked our main thread from terminating until all the workers did.

For fun, here is the output of `ps jf` when running your original script with no `join`s with the *only modification* being `time.sleep` thrown into `task2` so I could capture it running:

```
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
 6780  7385  7385  7385 pts/11    7677 Ss    1000   0:00 bash
 7385  7677  7677  7385 pts/11    7677 R+    1000   0:00  \_ ps jf
 6780  6866  6866  6866 pts/7     7646 Ss    1000   0:00 bash
 6866  7646  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00  \_ python test
 7646  7647  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      \_ python test
 7647  7672  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7647  7673  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7647  7674  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7647  7675  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7647  7676  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7646  7648  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      \_ python test
 7648  7665  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7648  7666  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7648  7667  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7648  7668  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7648  7669  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7646  7649  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      \_ python test
 7649  7656  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7649  7657  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7649  7658  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7649  7659  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7649  7660  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7646  7650  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      \_ python test
 7650  7652  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7650  7653  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7650  7654  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7650  7655  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7650  7670  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ python test
 7646  7651  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00      \_ python test
 7651  7661  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00          \_ python test
 7651  7662  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00          \_ python test
 7651  7663  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00          \_ python test
 7651  7664  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00          \_ python test
 7651  7671  7646  6866 pts/7     7646 S+    1000   0:00          \_ python test
```

You can see that our main process (the one that did `task0`) and the "first children" (the ones that did `task1`) are still alive, even though they clearly were out of python code to execute.  They are also all members of the same process group (`TPGID`).

## Sum it up, man

All of that is a long-winded way to say: `join` in your main thread is usually all you need, since you have the guarantee that any child processes will wait for *their* children to terminate before themselves terminating.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix-like systems (Linux, BSD, etc), `mp.Process` actually calls `os.fork`, and the `join` method of the resulting process object calls `wait` (or a variant)<sup>1</sup> to wait for it (i.e., waits for that *specific* process, not just any arbitrary process).

The child of a `fork` can only be `wait`-ed for by its parent,<sup>2</sup> so `task0` can wait for each `task1`, but not for any `task1`'s `task2`s.  Meanwhile each `task1` can wait for all its own `task2`s but not for any other `task1`'s `task2`s.

Because each `task2` is very short (and each process exits upon returning from its `target=` function), it's difficult to see any difference here whether you explicitly `join` or not.  You need to do something slower (e.g., `time.sleep()` or do some real work) to see any real differences.

---

<sup>1</sup>The actual call is `os.waitpid()`; see `multiprocessing/forking.py`.  The actual call is in the `poll` function.

<sup>2</sup>If a parent process exits without waiting for its children, those children are "orphaned" and passed off to PID 1 (init) as a surrogate parent.  Process 1 loops calling `wait` (or equivalent) to clean them up.

---

(The Windows variant uses different calls—it can't `fork`, for instance—and I don't work on Windows so I'm not sure how things really behave there.)